# Debug standalone java process

Tags: java, debugging, groovy

I have a standalone java application that i run through the command line using "java -cp . classWithMainMethod" command. My actual code is in c:\project, where i run the mvn assembly:single and extract the generated assembly into c:\genassembly.

I run the "java -cp . classWithMainMethod" from c:\genassembly which executes some groovy and java classes (the assembly needs tomcat to be running to execute the groovy scripts). I want to debug my groovy code (in eclipse or ggts) when this assembly runs. How can i do that?

I tried to set -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address="address" when i run the java -cp, but then can't figure out how to attach this to my eclipse/ggts workspace (I tried remote debug configs, stand alone configs etc.).

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually resolved this by:

1. Creating a new project for my generated assembly (groovy project from c:\genassembly in this case, but should hold true for java projects too).
2. Linking the actual source code in eclipse to this groject.
3. Setting up run configurations for running as Java application (specified the program, and vm arguments my program expects).
4. And debug as the the run config i created above.
5. Edit/Attach source lookup when at the breakpoint

In short, instead of running from the command shell, i ran the program from within eclipse by defining run configs.